# What Arquillian version should I use for JBoss EAP?

Tags: jboss-arquillian, jboss-eap-6

I've just installed JBoss EAP 6.4.3 and now I'm checking on Arquillian updates. According to http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/org/jboss/bom/eap/jboss-eap-bom-parent/6.4.3.GA/jboss-eap-bom-parent-6.4.3.GA.pom I'm stuck with version 1.1.0.

- Is this version the one that JBoss uses when developing JBoss EAP?
- Should I stick to this to be as compatible as possible or can I use the latest, greatest Arquillian version?
- What is the strategy of updates regarding Arquillian and JBoss EAP?

It would be great if someone from JBoss (e.g. Aslak Knutsen) could give me some hints.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine using the latest, but I doubt you'd get support for it if something didn't work right because it wasn't tested with that version of EAP.